# Inner function in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In JS, inner functions could be quite handy to simplify the code, something like:

```
function complexStuff() {
  function step1() { ... }
  function step2() { ... } 

  step1()
  step2()
}
```

Is it possible to use something similar in Ruby, or are there different approaches?

I don't like private methods because private methods are available to the whole class, and in this case, I want to limit the scope of the inner function even more--to just one method.

Comment: You should read on blocks, procs and lambdas. See https://www.blackbytes.info/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Ruby `lambda` is similar to an anonymous js `function`:

```
step1 = lambda {puts "I am a lambda!"}
step1.call "optional args", ...
```

Some shorthand:

```
f = -> {puts "Shorthand lambda"}
f.()
```

More info (including shorthand notation!!) [here](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/9994331)

Comment: Lambda also let you do things like `array.map(&some_lambda)` which helps clean up and clarify chains of Enumerable method calls.